# Load or Stress Testing Tool with URL Import Functionality

Tags: load-testing, stress-testing

Can someone recommend a load testing tool which allows you to either:

**a.** replay an IIS (7) log(s) to simulate a real live site daily run;
**b.** import a CSV or equivalent list of URLS so we can achieve a similar thing as above but at a URL level;
**c.** .net API so I can create simple tests easily from my list of URLS is also a good way to go.

I do not really want to record my tests.

I think I can do B) with WAPT but need to create an XML file manually, not too much grief, but wondering if any tools cover these scenarios out the box.

Comment: NeoLoad is a good load and stress testing tool http://www.neotys.com/product/demo-neoload.html

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Test Edition would require some code to parse the file into a suitable test run.

It is a great load testing solution.

Comment: Thanks Nat, will try to get hold of it.  Yep, a .net API to the load engine is also a good way to go for me, will add to question.

Comment: You could use LogParser to get the logs into .Net the webtest format for tests in Visual Studio is xml, so not completelty impossible to create.

Answer (score 1):

Our [load testing service](http://browsermob.com) lets you write a very simple script using JavaScript to pull data out of a CSV file and then fetch those URLs. For example, the following code would pluck 10 random URLs from the CSV file and fetch them as part of a single session:

```
var c = browserMob.openHttpClient();
var csv = browserMob.getCSV("urls.csv");

browserMob.beginTransaction();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    browserMob.beginStep("Step 1");
    var url = csv.random().get("url");
    c.get(url);
    browserMob.endStep();
}

browserMob.endTransaction();
```

The CSV file itself needs to be a normal CSV file with the first row containing a header named "url". This script would be run repeatedly for each virtual user participating in a load test.

Comment: Patrick, this looks great! but does this only run on internet sites? i.e. can I run it on my local dev machine?

Comment: Currently your website must be externally available (or inside the Amazon cloud). We are working on a behind-the-firewall solution, but it's not quite ready yet.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks, please post if you do have an update, I will look at other avenues for now.

Answer (score 1):

We have support for so called 'uri-format' in our open-source tool called [Yandex.Tank](https://github.com/yandex-load/yandex-tank) You simply put all your uris to a file, one uri -- one line, then specify headers in your load.ini like this:

```
[phantom]
address=example.org
rps_schedule=line(1, 1600, 2m)
headers = [Host: mts-maps.yandex.ru]
  [Connection: close] [Bloody: yes]
ammo_file = ammo.uri
```

ammo.uri:

```
/
/index.html
/1/example.html
/2/example.html
```